# Entropy of a chain

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

A chain has N segments which can be oriented in either the x or y directions. For each segment oriented along y, there is an energy penalty of $\epsilon$. We also know the end segment is at $(L_x, L_y)$. How can we define the entropy S as a function of E,N,Lx, and Ly?

I know $S=k*ln(\Omega)$, but is can you actually solve for the possible arrangements of the chain? I'm assume overlapping and crossing cannot be done.

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$S=k_b\ln\left(\begin{array}{c}
N\\
L_{y}
\end{array}\right)$$
which for $N=400$ looks like

```
DiscretePlot[Log[Binomial[400, L]], {L, 0, 400}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You know the starting position [$(0,0)$ I'm guessing?] and the ending position $(L_x, L_y)$. With just this, you could draw same possible arrangements:

```
       _ _f      _ _ _f
      |         |
s_ _ _|     s_ _|
```

In the above example, $(L_x,L_y)=(5,2)$. Both of the drawn possibilities have a total of five x's and two y's. There are many others.

Are you then trying to find the total number of ways to arrange $L_x$ x's and $L_y$ y's? That should get you started on your expression for the entropy. Note also $E$ is linked to $L_y$ somehow.

Comment: yea im pretty sure that is what i need

Comment: Alright. Been a while since I've thought about stat mech, so hopefully others will give feedback as well.